# PHP validation for registration form

Tags: php, registration

I have the problem I created a registration form and given database connection and database field values to enter the values in table. Here I am able to enter all field values in tables. If the field is empty, the empty value is entered, so I need to validate the registration form. If user enters empty value it should show the errors. If all the fields entered then only then should the data be submitted to the database. I also need to show if user already exists or not.

Comment: Please clean up your question; it is a _pain_ to read.  And why can't you just use 'if' statements to check the data before you put it into the database?

Comment: So basically you're telling `'give me teh codez'` without even trying anything from your side.

Comment: whatever you tried please post the code "as soon as possible"

Comment: Registration form in php with validation : http://allitstuff.com/registration-form-in-php-with-validation/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use required field validation standard on html using the `required` attribute 
 (Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the top of the html page)

`<input type="text" name="usrname" required="required" />`

or you can use jQuery for more elaborate validation using this example.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213138/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Validation-Plugin

Here is a great tutorial on how to validate on a username or email:

http://www.codeforest.net/username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery

Comment: `required` attribute is a HTML5 entity. I don't think OP is working with that

Comment: Server side verification is more reliable than client side, which sadly, totally missing from your answer.